# How to request a csv file from a url via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, csv, server, request

I'm looking for a way to request a csv file from any url to save it then. If possible only using fs, http, request and express modules.

For testing I tried it with

```
request('http://localhost:3000/data1.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data2.csv'))
```

but i always get as a resonse (data2.csv)

```
<pre>Cannot GET /data1.csv</pre>
```

Simplified Code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const request = require('request')

const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.listen(3000)

app.get('/download', (req, res) => {
    request('http://localhost:3000/data1.csv').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('data2.csv'))
})
```

The file data1.csv is saved in the root of my project folder. But is this also the root of my nodejs server from where I started it?

What I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would your "simplified code" make a request to _itself_? If that's actually your goal: why isn't there a route handler for `/data1.csv`? Why are you not ending the request? What's the purpose of `/download` to begin with? So many questions.

Comment: '/download' is only a route path to start the corresponding app.get(). The handler function is the arrow function. I didn't tought about the end() and the influence for this problem. I only want to know why I don't recieve the csv file? I simplified the code for easier understanding my core problem. The result should be a saved data2.csv in the same folder as data1.csv.

Comment: Your simplified code doesn't make sense because it's downloading `data1.csv` from your own (simplified) server that (apparently) has no handler to deal with requests for `data1.csv` (it can _only_ handle `/download`).

Comment: Thats correct, it makes no sence, but its an easy and comftable way to test the request function without any external url.

Comment: So again, explain how you think that your simplified server is supposed to return `data1.csv` if it doesn't have any handlers for it.

Comment: This exactly is my question. Does my server need an extra handler? If yes how could it look like? E.g. in this case only to respond with the data1.csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an explicit handler that returns `data1.csv`:

```
app.get('/data1.csv', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('data1.csv');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep! Incredibly simple. Note, the path must be absolute...